# Python/Django pass user input as keyword arguments?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, url

I am trying to pass what ever the user inputs into the url as keyword arguments (even if its not a real entry). When I try to assign the input name as the keyword arguments it fails.

```
HTML:
    <p class="search">
            <form method="GET" action="{% url 'job' %}" class="sidebar-form">
                <div class="ogsearchbar input-group">
                    <input class="searchbarz" type="text" name="user_input" id="user_input" placeholder="Enter Job Number" autocomplete="off" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </p>
```

Django:

```
 def get_job(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        formvar = request.GET['user_input']
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/jobs/' + formvar)
```

Comment: Have you tried something like: `<input type='text' name='q' placeholder='enter job number' value='{{request.GET.q}}'/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just go with javascript since my django code was not working with a request method when refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

What you want doesn't make sense. The `{{ }}` signs denote a context variable which is passed into the template from the server, before the template is rendered. But you're trying to use a value which is only defined when the user actually types something into the rendered page itself.

You could probably do this with some Javascript, but there doesn't seem to be much point. Drop the parameter from the URL and let the form send it in the query params, which you can access in your view as `request.GET`.

Comment: How would I structure this in a view? I understand what you are saying and edited my question.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Your form is set to use GET so you should use that in the view.

Comment: I added in my django code for my view but it is not working. When you enter a number and hit search it reloads the page but does not redirect to the newly received parameters. So the form is on a url named "/jobs/" and once I get the user input I want the page to redirect to "jobs/<user_input>"